# Video suport for React-Native-Web

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web, react-native-video

Is there any solutions for playing video in React-Native-Web

React-Native-Web: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

React-Native-Video: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how viable this solution is but since you are targeting web, you could use and abuse the `createElement`from `react-native-web` to create a video element.

For example you could create a stateless component like this:

```
import { createElement } from "react-native-web";

const Video = (props) => {
  const attrs = {
    src: props.source,
    poster: props.poster,
    controls: "controls"
  }
  return createElement("video", attrs)
}
export default Video
```

And then use it in your app like this:

```
<Video
  source={require("./stock_video.mp4")}
  poster={'https://www.fillmurray.com/480/300'}
/>
```

Here's a little [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-butterfly-qpbvh) how it would work.

Comment: How can I use srcObject in react native?

Comment: `createElement` no longer exists and is replaced by `unstable_createElement`. https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/unstable-apis/