# React Native Web - Control the html tag generated by View?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I have a react native web project. At one point, I would like my `View` instead of generating a `<div>` to generate a `<label>` element.

Is there a way to control this? I am hoping for some sort of `htmlTag` attribute that gets ignored if this is not compiling for a browser environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a `component` prop but it's removed in favor of `accessibilityRole` ([Remove `component` prop](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/23)).

You can use [`accessibilityRole`](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/guides-accessibility--page) to specify the `label` tag and even create a custom element using it:

```jsx
function Label({ text }) {
  return <View accessibilityRole="label">{text}</View>
}
```

and then use it like this:

```jsx
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Label text="Test input:"/>
          <TextInput name="test-input"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Check this working Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@clytras/change-rn-web-div-tag

Answer (score 0):

How about making your own wrapper of View? It could check what environment it is running in, and then if it's in a browser then you can return the label element instead.

Comment: How would that work? Can you provide an example? The entire issue that I'm having is that I don't know how to emit an html tag that is not react native - as far as I know, since its react native not react that's running this that's not possible without some support for RN

Comment: You just gave and idea that make sense, but that won't work when return direct HTML tag under React Native control. Unless there is a component for which RNW is returning s special HTML tag, you don't have control directly.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I found an answer that could be helpful. The person said to use `createElement` from `react-native-web`, and returning an element created with `video` tag or any HTML tag. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333885/5565544

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `accessibilityLabel` prop on the `TextInput`, which will add an `aria-label` prop to the React Native code when it compiles to html for web.
In terms of accessibility, this accomplishes the same effect as a `label` attribute. See the React Native web docs on accessibility: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/accessibility/

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <TextInput accessibilityLabel="test-input" name="test-input"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```